# Dropdown text field within show.gsp

Tags: grails

So within my grails application I have a form consisting of multiple fields. One of these fields is being named 'mandatory'. Currently it's a text field that allows one character to be inputted but I'd like the field to be a drop down with the option of blank, Y or N to be select-able.

This is how my text field for mandatory looks now:

```
<g:textField name="mandatory" maxlength="1" value="${templateInputInstance?.mandatory}"/>
```

This is what I have come up with for the dropdown:

```
<select name="mandatory" maxlength="1" value="${templateInputInstance?.mandatory">
    <option>Y</option>
    <option>N</option>
</select>
```

This allows me to select Y or N however when I hit submit at the bottom of the form the value for 'mandatory' isn't saved and shown in the show.gsp page.

Can someone tell me why that is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand You correctly, You want to set textField value depending on the select value?

If so,
You should use javascript, for example:

js:

```
...
$('#mandatory').change(function()
{
    $('#textFieldMandatory').val($(this).val());
});
...
```

Yours html:

```
<g:textField name="textFieldMandatory" maxlength="1" value="${templateInputInstance?.mandatory}"/>
<select name="mandatory" maxlength="1" value="${templateInputInstance?.mandatory">
    <option>Y</option>
    <option>N</option>
</select>
```

Or if You want to set this value after submitting a form, You should use Ajax.

## Edit

As Jamie write:

```
<g:select name="mandatory" from=" YN" maxlength="1" value="${templateInputInstance?.mandatory}"/>
```

solve the problem.

Comment: I want to replace the textField with select. I've done that with this below:

<select> name="mandatory" maxlength="1" value="${templateInputInstance?.mandatory}"
                <option></option>
  <option>Y</option>
  <option>N</option>
</select>

This gives me a dropdown with options (blank, Y, N) however when I hit submit on the form the value for mandatory isn't saved.

Comment: So if You want to get value after submitting a form, you should use  ajax for it, and save selected value, and then set it to the textField.

Comment: Solved by using <g:select> which I didn't know existed:

<g:select name="mandatory" from=" YN" maxlength="1" value="${templateInputInstance?.mandatory}"/>